# Detect if my page is in a frame from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

Is there a way to detect if my page is inside of a frame from my C# ASP.NET Code Behind?

I know there are ways to break out of frames, or detect frames, using javascript, but I'm not interested in that for this case. I want to know if there is a way to detect the frame server-side before the page makes it's first trip to the browser, i.e. if there is some kind of indication of this in the request.

Comment: Where would the detection "script" be placed? I'm not sure I understand the question perfectly, but I think from the page in the frame it could be quite problematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, there's nothing sent in the headers of the request indicating that the page is in a frame - and that's all you really have to go on.

The best you could do is take a look at the [Referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property, and if it comes from a known framing site (i.e. images.google.com etc) treat it as suspicious.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a little late, but here I go...

The best thing you could do if you want to know on the server-side is to use JavaScript to redirect your page if it is inside a frame.  For example, use this JavaScript to redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(top.location.href!= window.location.href){
    window.parent.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1/frame.aspx?frame=yes";
}
</script>
```

Then in frame.aspx you would know the previous page was in a frame.  You could add more info to the querystring if you need to.