# Block direct access to page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a nginx server with php installed on it. I want to disable direct access to some php/html pages. However, I want to show those pages inside an iframe of my own website. For example:

```
mysite.com/test.html (direct access is blocked)
<iframe src="mysite.com/test.html/"></iframe> (this will show the page on my site)
<iframe src="OTHERSITES.com/test.html/"></iframe> (cannot show contents)
```

I would like to do it in php. However, if there is no way to do it in php I am fine with a javascript solution.

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508176/detect-if-my-page-is-in-a-frame-from-code-behind) might be relevant.

Comment: An iframe also opens the page with direct access, so the server has no telling if the page was opened in an iframe or browser window. You can only check with Javascript if the page is opened in an iframe or not and then act based on that. Please note that users can disable javascript.

Comment: @MinusFour suggestion answered my question. Thus, I marked it as a duplicate. Thanks.